# Async/await Mongoose collection,why my Post collection is not created?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I will explain what I tried with this code

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/postdb', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }).then(() => console.log('Successfully connect to MongoDB.'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Connection error', err));

 
  async function createPost() {
    try {
      const jean = await User.create({
        username : 'Jean', email: 'jtigana@aol.com',
      });
      const c1 = await Comment.create({postedBy : jean, body: 'Enfent terrible' });
      await Post.create({title: 'Vou comer voce! ',
        body: 'What a wonderful life!',
        postedBy: jean,
        comments: c1,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  createPost();
```

My PostSchema

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment',
  }] 
});
```

I expected 3 collections,idea is that later other users could add comments in same post. MongoDB compass
[image]

I run my code from terminal

```
node --trace-warnings --unhandled-rejections=strict index.js
```

Try/catch block is not complaining. Why is the third collection missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have stated postedBy and comments as an ObjectId, but you are passing an object instead of the id. Do the following:

```
      await Post.create({title: 'Vou comer voce! ',
        body: 'What a wonderful life!',
        postedBy: jean.id,
        comments: c1.id,
      });
```

Now you are passing both Id's.

Also, you have declared the post as PostSchema but then you try to create a Post which is not declared. You should rename Post.create to PostSchema.create or PostSchema to Post.

Comment: I have reviewed and the issue is that you have declared de post as PostSchema but you are a post which is not declared. It should be PostSchema.create and not Post.create.

Comment: module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema); Module export is OK.

Comment: Are you importing it correctly? I have copied your code and it saves the 3 collections in the db.

Comment: Yes,the problem was with MongoDB Atlas.Works fine now!